# Variable needs explicit type from parse()

Tags: rust

I am trying to create a method that takes the input from stdin. It should loop until the input is a valid integer that I can parse to an integer. The error I am getting is this:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed for `Result<F, _>`
 --> src/lib.rs:9:13
  |
9 |         let parsed_int_result = line.trim().parse(); // Getting the error here
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
help: consider giving `parsed_int_result` an explicit type, where the placeholders `_` are specified
  |
9 |         let parsed_int_result: Result<F, _> = line.trim().parse(); // Getting the error here
  |                              ++++++++++++++
```

I think the match statement is kind of wrong, but I dont know how I should solve it. I just want to catch the `Err()` and try again until the Result-Value is `Ok()`.

```
pub fn input_int_with_message(msg: &str) -> i32 {
    let mut parsed_int;
    println!("{msg}");
    loop {
        let mut line = String::new();
        std::io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut line)
            .expect("Couldn't read from stdin");
        let parsed_int_result = line.trim().parse(); // Getting the error here
        let parsed_int = match parsed_int_result {
            Ok(integer) => {
                integer;
                break;
            },
            Err(error) => println!("Input was not an integer. Try again:"),
        };
    }
    parsed_int
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code declares `let mut parsed_int` at the top and returns it at the bottom, but `let parsed_int = ...` in the loop shadows the outer variable. It's not actually assigning to the outer `parsed_int`, which prevents Rust from inferring that the inner `parsed_int` is `i32`.

As it happens, you don't actually need a `parsed_int` variable. You can use `break integer` to cause the loop to evaluate to `integer`. Since the loop is the last expression in the function, that will cause the function to effectively return `integer`. Rust is then able to infer that `integer` is `i32`.

```
pub fn input_int_with_message(msg: &str) -> i32 {
    println!("{msg}");
    loop {
        let mut line = String::new();
        std::io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut line)
            .expect("Couldn't read from stdin");
        let parsed_int_result = line.trim().parse(); // Getting the error here
        match parsed_int_result {
            Ok(integer) => {
                break integer;
            }
            Err(_) => println!("Input was not an integer. Try again:"),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=98811e11d8fa8cbf5a92cada810a863d)

Comment: Thank you very much that works. I didnt realise i was shadowing the variable, but that makes sense if i redeclare it.

Answer (score 1):

[`str::parse`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) is defined as:

```
pub fn parse<F>(&self) -> Result<F, <F as FromStr>::Err>
where
    F: FromStr
```

You need to instruct the compiler as to which type you want it to call `parse` for. You can write:

```rs
let parsed_int_result: Result<i32, _> = line.trim().parse();
```

Comment: If i do that i have to give `parsed_int` the value of i32 and i cant just `println()` my error message because it expects a `i32` obviously.